# How to Install & Setup MEAN Stack on Ubuntu (MongoDB, Express.JS, Angular.JS, Node.JS)

Tags: application-development, web-development, ubuntu-website

I have started learning to mean stack web development which is an open-source JavaScript framework used for developing robust applications. It is a complete packet of software tools that have everything for building dynamic websites and applications.

As a beginner, I am having issues related to installing and setup Mean Stack. I don't even know the basics of installing. I don't know what would be the consequences if I did something wrong in setup or installing.

Comment: You asked EXACT same question yesterday saying it was installing on windows. What has changed. my guess nothing.

Comment: I would like to inform you that was supposed to be ubuntu but I wrote windows mistakenly because mostly I worked on windows so that is why I wrote windows instead of ubuntu. Thanks for asking. but now it is sorted...!!

Comment: Did you try and follow the official installation instructions for those packages? That would be a good place to start. Also, it's a good idea to experiment in a VM, and only install on your production machine when you have sorted things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you see stacks like LAMP and MEAN, a person would install the software in the order of the acronym from left to right. For example:

LAMP = Linux ⇢ Apache ⇢ MySQL ⇢ PHP
MEAN = MongoDB ⇢ Express ⇢ Angular ⇢ Node

You don't *need* to follow the order with everything, but it generally helps to do so. Let's get you started.

**I don't even know the basics of installing...**

First you will need an Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.04 installation ready to use. If you do not already have Ubuntu installed, [download the version you would like](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), [get it installed](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview), then continue with this answer.

**I don't know what would be the consequences if I did something wrong in setup or installing**

The consequences would be that you learn how to fix your computer if something goes wrong. This isn't necessarily a bad thing.

**How to build the MEAN stack**

The following steps will give you the very basics of what you need on a modern Ubuntu installation. Please note that these steps work for 20.04 and 21.04. I did not do any testing on older releases or other flavours of Ubuntu.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Install MongoDB:

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install mongodb
   ```

   Now you can start MongoDB:

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```
2. Setup Git, nom, Express and Angular:

   ```
   sudo apt install git npm
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   npm install express --save
   npm install angular
   ```
3. Install Node.js:

   ```
   sudo apt install nodejs
   ```

   Now you can test that Node is properly installed by calling the prompt:

   ```
   nodejs
   ```
4. Start building your websites

There's a great deal more that can be done, but these basic steps will give you everything you need to *start* learning MEAN development.